# A little help with the Uniswap V3 flash loan arbitrage code

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap, flash-loans, arbitrage

I'm trying to use flash loans on Uniswap V3 to trade across different pools (two of these four: 0.01%, 0.05%, 0.30%, 1.00%)

I've tried running codes from multiple tutorials:

https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/uniswap-v3-flash/

https://alexvanzyl.com/create-a-flash-loan-with-uniswap-v3

https://jamesbachini.com/flash-loans/

Only with James Bachini's code was I able to run the flash or flashLoan function (I was able to receive a SimpleFlashLoan.) This is the code:

https://github.com/jamesbachini/Solidity-Snippets/blob/main/contracts/UniswapFlashLoan.sol

Every time I put in the same information in "flash" from the other two codes as "flashLoan" from James Bachini's code, the transaction fails.

Also, from James Bachini's code, I'm not able to run the UniswapV3FlashCallback function. I keep getting an error, because I'm not positive what the following is supposed to say: _fee0, _fee1, _data.

It's either an "error encoding arguments" because not everything has been filled out, or an error estimating gas and executing the function inside the contract (the transaction failing)

I've put stuff like "500, 100, 0x", "100, 500, 0x", "100, 3000, 0x", "3000, 100, 0x", "10000, 3000, 0x", sometimes I'll put the very same things with 0x00 as the bytes instead of 0x. Nothing has ever worked. I tried putting it in after I receive the loan.

I have already been struggling to figure out a fix myself by googling it or something, and it's super frustrating! I haven't even seen James Bachini fill out the _fee0, _fee1, and _bytes.